# Plotting aligned histograms in the same graph

Tags: r

I would need to plot aligned histograms in the same graph from the rows of a matrix. In the following example I would need to plot 5 stacked histograms. However, the hist command plots one histogram of the whole matrix. Is there any workaround I could use?

Thanks in advance.

Arturo

```
x <- 10; y <- 10; g <- 5
dat <- matrix(rnorm((x + y) * g), ncol = x + y)
hist (dat)
```

Comment: so you want individual barplots for each row and you want them stacked vertically for comparison?

Comment: That's correct. Each row should have its own y-axis and a shared x-axis.

Answer (score 1):

`ggplot` do it easily (it need a long form data).

```
library(tidyr); library(dplyr); library(ggplot2)

df <- dat %>% t() %>% as.data.frame() %>% gather(row)  # chage data into a long format
Breaks <- hist(dat, plot=F)$breaks                     # get (or decide) breaks

ggplot(df, aes(x = value, fill = row)) + geom_histogram(position = "stack", breaks = Breaks)
```

[image]

**[EDITED]**
    Is this what you want ?

```
  ## original
ggplot(df, aes(x = value)) + 
  geom_histogram(breaks = Breaks) +
  facet_wrap(~ row)            # make histogram par group.

  ## modified
ggplot(df, aes(x = value, fill = row)) +                 # change fill colour
  geom_histogram(breaks = Breaks) +
  facet_wrap(~ row, ncol = 1) +                          # bring graphs into line
   #  facet_wrap( ~ row, ncol = 1, scales = "free_y")    # if you don't want fixed scale
  theme(strip.background = element_blank(), strip.text.x = element_blank()) # delete labels
```

[image]

**[EDITED2: base_plot approach]**
Base plot save the time.

```
 ## example data
x <- 1500; y <- 1500; g <- 30
set.seed(1); dat <- matrix(rnorm((x + y) * g), ncol = x + y)

 ## decide breaks
Breaks <- seq(-4.5, 4.5, 0.5)

 ## change par() to draw multiple graphs
par.old <- par(mar = c(0.1, 4.0, 0.1, 0.5), oma = c(4, 0, 0, 0), mfrow = c(nrow(dat), 1))

for(i in 1:nrow(dat)) {
  hist(dat[,i], breaks = Breaks, xaxt = "n", xlab = "", main = "")
#  grid(NULL)
    }
par(new=T)
hist(dat[,nrow(dat)], breaks = Breaks, main = "", yaxt = "n", 
     xlab = "x", ylab = "", border = NA)          # add x-axis

par(par.old)
```

Comment: Thanks, but I need to separate each row in my plot so that its contribution is immediately visible

Comment: Thank you. This is close to what I want. Now I need to understand the code .. :-)

Comment: Thanks also for the commented code. I have one more question, if you don't mind. Sometimes, I need to plot arrays that are up to 30x6000, rather than 5x20, like in the example I provided. I noticed that in this case the procedure takes a long time. I was thinking that may be removing the colors could speed things up. Do you think that this would be feasible?

Comment: @Arturo; Unfortunately, as far as I have experienced on my environment, clolors have little effect with the time. Of course, you can remove the hist's colors by deleting `fill = row` and change theme simply by inserting other ggtheme before `theme(strip...)`, for example, `... + facet_wrap(~ row, ncol = 1) + theme_minimal() + theme(strip.background = element_blank(), strip.text.x = element_blank())` (see [ggtheme](http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/ggtheme.html)). I don't have a good idea to save the time.

Comment: @Arturo; I added another approach.

Comment: Wow! Now it is blazingly fast! This is certainly the way to go. Thank you so much. Now I need to understand the code :-), though you already did a good job in commenting it.

Comment: I have one last question if you don't mind. How would you code the remaining part if the first two lines were the following:

Comment: x <- 3000; y <- 2778; g <- 30
set.seed(1); dat <- matrix(rnorm((x + y) * g, mean = 10), ncol = g)

Comment: Sorry , I mistyped the previous two posts.

How would you code the remaining part of your script, if the fist two lines were the followign?

x <- 3000; y <- 2778; g <- 30
set.seed(1); dat <- matrix(rnorm((x + y) * g, mean = 10), ncol = g)

Thanks again.

Comment: I apologize again. It seems that I cannot type anymore. In my previous posts,I was meaning that I have 5778 columns and 30 rows. Therefore, the first two lines od the code should be:

x <- 3000; y <- 2778; g <- 30

set.seed(1); dat <- matrix(rnorm((x + y) * g, mean = 10), ncol = x+y)

Sorry for messing things up.

Comment: @Arturo; (advice: you can delete your own comments) The code you have to modify is only one, `Breaks`. let's run `range(dat)` (in your comment case, it is `[1] 5.457878 14.313621`) and define your `Breaks`. For example, `seq(5, 15, 1)` or `seq(5, 14.5, 0.5)` look suitable for the `Breaks`. You can refer to `hist()`'s breaks some methods give, such as `hist(dat[,5], plot=F, breaks="scott")$breaks`

Answer (score -1):

This is an approach I am using in order to produce two histograms in the same chart.

Consider having a dataset where the column x is the continuous var and column y is the factor variable; each level will produce one histogram. Please find below an example of code using ggplot2:

```
OverlayedHist <- function(mData       ,
                          featureVar  ,
                          grouper     ,
                          mbinwidth   ,
                          mTitle      ,
                          mxlab       ,
                          mylab       ,
                          mlegendTitle
){

  # function name: OverlayedHist
  #       purpose: To produce overlayed histograms against a grouping variable
  #         Input: 
  #         mData: dataset object in data.table format
  #    featureVar: name of continuous variable to produce histogram
  #       grouper: the grouping variable to produce the histogram 
  #     mbinwidth: binwidth (see ggplot2 parameters)
  #        mTitle: Character to define title
  #         mxlab: Character to define xlab name
  #         mylab: Character to define ylab name
  #  mlegendTitle: Character to define legend title

  library(data.table)
  library(ggplot2)
  library(plotly)

  p <- ggplot(allDat, aes(eval(parse(text = featureVar)), fill = eval(parse(text = grouper)))) +
    geom_histogram(alpha = 0.7, position = 'identity', binwidth = mbinwidth) + 
    scale_fill_manual(values=c("#377EB8","#E41A1C")) + 
    ggtitle(mTitle) +
    xlab(mxlab) + ylab(mylab) + 
    guides(fill=guide_legend(title=mlegendTitle)) + theme(plot.title = element_text(size=10))


  return(ggplotly(p))

}
```

I hope this helps.

Cheers!
K.

Comment: Could  you please post some working code to test your method?

Comment: Above you can find a more detailed version of an interactive plot